# When does a transaction get commited (by default)?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am writing a pretty small spring boot application, without any special transaction related properties. My REST controller calls `save(myEntity)` on the repository.

When will database transaction be committed?

Will it be committed

- as part of the `save` method? (probably too early, an exception could rise up later)
- when my own code is done and returns to the spring boot code?
- even later, when the serialization of the result is done?
- or is this depending on the database driver?

Example code `dbtransaction/Application.java`:

```
package dbtransaction;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.UUID;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/thing")
class ThingRestController {

    private ThingRepository thingRepository;

    public ThingRestController(ThingRepository thingRepository) {
        this.thingRepository = thingRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Thing createNew() {
        return thingRepository.save(new Thing());
    }
}

@Repository
interface ThingRepository extends JpaRepository<Thing, String> {
}

@Entity
class Thing {
    @Id
    public UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

Example pom `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>dbtransaction</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Given that you have no explicity transactionality I'm fairly confident that it will run in auto commit mode which means the save method will start and stop the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you commit depends on your transactional scope.  In the code example you provided, you did not specify any transactional scope so it will default to your repository method; it will commit after your call `thingRepository.save`.

Note that the default implementation for `JpaRepository` is `SimpleJpaRepository` and if you look at that class, you'll see it annotates its save method with `@Transactional`. That, therefore, becomes your default boundary of your transaction.  You can easily change your transactional scope by specifying `@Transactional` on an outer method.